# Pydantic default value from other class' field

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there any chance to set as default value value from other class' field:

```
class Data(BaseModel):
    field_1: Optional[str] = Data2.field_2


class Data2(BaseModel):
    field_2: Optional[str] = ''
```

I've tried with:

```
Data2 = ForwardRef('Data2')
.
.
.
Data.update_forward_refs()
```

getting: cannot encode object: ForwardRef('Data2'), of type: <class
'typing.ForwardRef

Comment: You can change declaration order (`Data2` first).
In Data use instance `Data2().field_2` as default value. Then you can simply use: 
`data1 = Data()`
`data1.field_1` 
output: `''`

But this is not a good idea. If you describe your whole case we can find beter and probably simpler solutiuon.

Comment: I've refactored code a bit and don't need it anymore, thanks anyway ...